# What exactly does mesh.optimize do?

Tags: optimization, unity-game-engine, mesh

I have a mesh that I create every frame in using the combine meshes function.  I cannot get the mesh to appear if I do not call the `mesh.optimize` function on it; using recalculate normals or recalculate bounds does not help.

Why do I need to call `mesh.optimize`, and what does it do exactly?  I want to do only the things necessary to get my object to display on the screen since `mesh.optimize` is very expensive.

Answer (score 2):

From my testing it appears to rearrange the vertices so that the ones nearest to the outside edges of the object are first in the array, and as they get closer to the center of the object they get sorted to the end.  I don't know what else is taking place, but this is very noticeable if you slowly print out the vertex positions in order before and after the optimize.

Here's a simple video showing Optimize on vs off if interested: https://youtu.be/AQoNM_Q-uQM

Answer (score 1):

From Unity's [reference](http://unity3d.com/support/documentation/ScriptReference/Mesh.Optimize.html):

> This operation might take a while but will make the geometry displayed be faster. For example it generates triangle strips out of the triangles. You should use it if you generate a mesh from scratch procedurally and you want to trade better runtime performance against higher load time. Internally it tri-strips your model and optimizes the triangles for vertex cache locality. For imported models you should never call this as the import pipeline already does it for you.

That's pretty much all the information that they have up there, but hopefully that helps give you a little more understanding of what's going on under the hood.

Comment: Yeah, I read that but that doesn't do me any good in trying to figure out why it's necessary to display things.  It says it makes geometry displayed faster, but I don't need that.  I just want to know why it makes my geometry display, since it's being called every frame it's not helping in that way anyways since the function takes longer than the optimization it gives.